# CSS Margin auto center for <li> tag

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"/>
</head>
<style>
body,html,aside,article,header,nav,footer,ul,section,div,li,ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

aside,article,header,nav,footer,section,div,ul {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html {
    background:#F1C4F2;
}
body {
    width:1000px;
    background:#FF53A9;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size:12px;

}

#header{
    width:98%;
    background-color:#F081F3;
    padding:1%;
    color:white;
    font-size:1.2em;
}

#nav {
    width:98%;
    background-color:#C043AA;
    font-size:1.1em;
    padding:1%;
}

ul{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%
}

li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:8%;
    color:white;

}
     OR
/*   
     li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:8%;
    color:white;

}

    */ 
</style>


<body>

<div id="header">
some.com
</div><!--HEADER-->

<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Bio</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
    <li>Upcoming Projects</li>
    <li>Videos</li>
</ul>
</div><!--NAVIGATION-->

<div id="footer"> </div> <!--FOOTER-->

</body>
</html>
```

I have `'UL'` tag inside a `'NAV' <DIV>`,for my navigation i have created a `'LI'` items and floated it and when i apply ""`margin:0 auto`"" it doesn't apply. 
Even when I use ""`display:inline-block`""(this section is commented out) to '`LI`'.Js

Fiddle link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cwo0uz5/)

Comment: What are you trying to center, the list or the list items...it's not clear.

Comment: the 'ul' I want it in the centre of the "nav" 'div'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add text-align:center for your `<ul>` and remove `float:left` from `<li>` and use `display:inline-block;` **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ckvpe8th/1/)**

```
ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:8%;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will center your `ul` and i've also added `overflow:hidden` so that the floats are contained (the `li`).

```
ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

You were applying `margin:0px auto` to a 100% width element which wont work.

The result: [fixed](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbLZwg)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `ul` **is** centered but it's 100% wide so I am assuming that, in fact. you want the list items centered in the `ul`.

So, remove any floats, set `text-align:center` on the `ul` and make the `li` display as `inline-block`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  background: #F1C4F2;
}
body {
  width: 1000px;
  background: #FF53A9;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header {
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #F081F3;
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#nav {
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #C043AA;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  background: blue;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 2%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="header">
    some.com
  </div>
  <!--HEADER-->

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Bio</li>
      <li>Gallery</li>
      <li>Upcoming Projects</li>
      <li>Videos</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--NAVIGATION-->

  <div id="footer"></div>
  <!--FOOTER-->
```